# Display a json word from a sentence with different color

Tags: javascript, spring

I try to make an korean vocab app and i have a problem, for example if the word that user wanna learn it s "남자" and i give to him first sentence "남자이에요" i wanna "남자" word to be red and the rest part to be black , in my code "koword" represent the word "남자" and korfirstSentence it s my sentence "남자이에요"

html code:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">TEST</button>

 <section id="engWordSection">
<h1 class="englishWordInline" > English word: </h1>
<h1 class="englishWordInline" id="engWord" > </h1>
 </section>

  <section id="koreanWordSection">
<h1 class="koreanWordInline">Korean word: </h1>
<h1 class="koreanWordInline" id="koWord" ></h1>
 </section>

<section id="firstSentenceSection" >
<h1 class="firstSentenceInline">First Korean Sentence: </h1>
<h1 class="firstSentenceInline" id="firstS"></h1>

</section>

 <section id="secondSentenceSection">
 <h1 class="secoundSentenceInline">Second Korean Sentence: </h1>
 <h1 class="secoundSentenceInline" id="secondS"></h1>
  </section>

 <section id="thirdSentenceSection">
<h1 class="thirdSentenceInline">Third Korean Sentence: </h1>
<h1 class="thirdSentenceInline" id="thirdS" >  </h1>
 </section>


  <br>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/slideshowJs.js"></script>
```

js code:

```
function myFunction() {



let userInput=document.getElementById("field1").value;
console.log(userInput);





var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

        test=JSON.parse(this.responseText);



        document.getElementById("koWord").innerHTML = test.koword;
        document.getElementById("secondS").innerHTML=test.kosecondSentence;
        document.getElementById("thirdS").innerHTML=test.kothirdSentence;
        document.getElementById("engWord").innerHTML=test.kowordTranslation;
        document.getElementById("firstS").innerHTML = test.korfirstSentence;


        console.log(test);








    }
};


xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/words/showSentences?word="  + userInput, true);
xhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your sentence string with a word that is wrapped with some tag.

STYLE:

```
<style>
   .highlighted{
     color:red;
   }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<h1 id="keyWord"></p>
<h1 id="sentence"></p>
```

JS:

```
<script>
  var word = "Korea";
  var sentence = "I like Korea:)";

  document.querySelector("#keyWord").innerHTML = word;
  document.querySelector("#sentence").innerHTML = sentence.replace(
    word,
    `<b class="highlighted">` + word + `</b>`
  );
</script>
```